# breadth first search in c

Tags: c, data-structures, graph, breadth-first-search

i am trying to implement a bfs in c

these are the data structures

```
typedef struct linkedlist { // linked list of ints (for use in Node)
  int index;
  struct linkedlist *next;
} List;

typedef struct { // a Node of a Graph
  char *name;
  List *outlist; // adjacency list
  int outdegree; 
  int visited;// length of outlist
  int indegree;
  //double pagerank_score; //not needed for this exercise
} Node;

typedef struct {
  // your code goes here
  int MaxSize;
  Node *table;
} Graph;
```

this is my search code

```
#include "graph.h"

/* Good luck */
void bfs(Graph *mygraph){
//int i=0;
int u;

 for(u=1;u<mygraph->MaxSize;u++)
   mygraph->table[u].visited=0;
 for(u=1;u<mygraph->MaxSize;u++){
   if(mygraph->table[u].visited==0){
     printf("%s \n",mygraph->table[u].name);
     visit(u,mygraph);
   }
 }
}

void visit(int u,Graph *mygraph){
 // i ++;
  List *current;
  mygraph->table[u].visited++;
  current= mygraph->table[u].outlist;

  while (current!=NULL) { 
    if(mygraph->table[current->index].visited==0)
      printf("%i \n",current->index);
      visit(current->index,mygraph);
      current = current->next;}

}
```

this **segfaults** for some reason i do not know why is my implementation wrong ?

Comment: You should use a debugger to find out *where* it segfaults.

Comment: Can you run it through GDB and show a backtrace where your program is segfaulting?

Comment: Whitespace is cheap nowadays. Don't be afraid to use it.

Comment: Add some sanity checking for current->index, and make sure outlist and next are all valid pointers. In other words, make sure your graph is set up right before you walk it.

Comment: This `for (u = 1; ...)` looks wrong. The usual is to start at 0 (`for (u = 0; ...)`)

Comment: As @Martinho said, stepping through a debugger will definitely show you the problem.   If you don't know how to use a debugger, even a liberal sprinkling of printf-statements will show you how far your program runs before the seg-fault.

Comment: In the function visit(): could it be, that you forgot to put curly braces after if? If a node was not visited before, do you really only want to print that node or visit it too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few optimizations here, but your code looks mostly correct (I haven't finished my own BFS implementation yet). Here's what to think about:

1. You're checking for visited == 0 unnecessarily - many times over. You've already set your node as visited, there's no need to check if is equal to zero.

   ```
    for(u=1;u<mygraph->MaxSize;u++){
        if(mygraph->table[u].visited==0){ /* Silly */
   ```
2. Consider if you have allocated each block of memory that all your pointers are pointing to. That's probably the source of your segmentation fault.
3. Whitespace, damn it.